# Get php object values into array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I want what is output from the initial `echo $zip` to be stuffed into an array as a simple integer stack... I have tried `[]`,`{}` and a variety of other accessors... Thanks again!

I have:

```
$userZip = new ZipCode($userZip);
$theZips = array();

foreach ($userZip->getZipsInRange(0, 10) as $miles => $zip) {

    echo $zip . '<BR>';

    $theZips = $zip;

}

print_r($theZips);

// print_r($theZips) output: 
ZipCode Object ( [zip_code_id:ZipCode:private] => 33816 [zip_code:ZipCode:private] => 21115 [lat:ZipCode:private] => 42.48 [lon:ZipCode:private] => -83.02 [city:ZipCode:private] => CENTER Ville [county:ZipCode:private] => [area_code:ZipCode:private] => [time_zone:ZipCode:private] => [state_prefix:ZipCode:private] => VA [state_name:ZipCode:private] => [mysql_table] => zip_code [mysql_conn] => [mysql_row:ZipCode:private] => Array ( [miles] => 8.88798662376604 [zip_code_id] => 33816 [zip_code] => 21119 [city] => City [state_prefix] => VA [lat] => 42.48 [lon] => -83.02 ) [print_name:ZipCode:private] => 48015 [location_type:ZipCode:private] => [miles] => 8.88798662376604 )
```

// UPDATED// thanks tried that but I get objects

print_R($theZips);

// output:

Array
(
    [0] => ZipCode Object
        (
            [zip_code_id:ZipCode:private] => 34026
            [zip_code:ZipCode:private] => 21115
            [lat:ZipCode:private] => 42.58
            [lon:ZipCode:private] => -82.91
            [city:ZipCode:private] => City Ville
            [county:ZipCode:private] => 
            [area_code:ZipCode:private] => 
            [time_zone:ZipCode:private] => 
            [state_prefix:ZipCode:private] => VA
            [state_name:ZipCode:private] => 
            [mysql_table] => zip_code
            [mysql_conn] => 
            [mysql_row:ZipCode:private] => Array
                (
                    [miles] => 0.000225049859756069
                    [zip_code_id] => 34026
                    [zip_code] => 21115
                    [city] => City Ville
                    [state_prefix] => VA
                    [lat] => 42.58
                    [lon] => -82.91
                )

```
        [print_name:ZipCode:private] => 21119
        [location_type:ZipCode:private] => 
        [miles] => 0.000225049859756069
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($userZip->getZipsInRange(0, 10) as $miles => $zip) {

    echo $zip . '<BR>';    

    $theZips[] = $zip;  //push $zip into $theZips array    

}
```

Comment: thanks but that does not seem to be getting the desired results, it appears to be an object array